# Mysql: How to retrieve data on weekly basis

Tags: mysql

I have a data like this:

[image]

And now i want to print this data on weekly basis like this

```
+------------+-----------+
|    weeks   | sum(count)| 
+----------- +-----------+
| week 1     |  2526     | 
| week 2     |  26987    |
+------------+-----------+
```

This query sum all mimi_count but i want data in above figure format may be it has to with

> group by

.I have searched a lot but could't find what i want

```
SELECT sum(mimie_count) as mimie 
FROM statistics 
WHERE mimiDate >    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Comment: ADD `GROUP BY WEEK(mimiDate)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
WEEK(mimiDate) weeks,
sum(mimie_count) as mimie 
FROM statistics 
WHERE mimiDate >    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 WEEK)
GROUP BY WEEK(mimiDate)
ORDER BY mimiDate;
```

**Note:** If you want last X weeks sum week wise then use this `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL X WEEK)`. Also note that `WEEK` function assumes the start of the week is `Monday`

**EDIT:**
If you want the first column like you stated then you need to adopt the following query:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('week ',WEEK(mimiDate)) weeks,
    sum(mimie_count) as mimie 
    FROM statistics 
    WHERE mimiDate >    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 WEEK)
    GROUP BY WEEK(mimiDate)
    ORDER BY mimiDate;
```

**For Specific date range search:**

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('week ',WEEK(mimiDate)) weeks,
    sum(mimie_count) as mimie 
    FROM statistics 
    WHERE mimiDate BETWEEN '2016-01-21' AND ' 2016-03-05'
    GROUP BY WEEK(mimiDate)
    ORDER BY mimiDate;
```

Comment: What if i have to get data by weeks by giving specific dates like 2016-01-21 to 2016-03-05

Comment: `2016-01-21` is the 4th day of the corresponding week. Now do you want to avoid the previous three days of that week? It's your decision and query will be formulated based on your decision.@MTalhaAfzal

Comment: where i edit those specific dates (start date - end date) in your query. I am sorry for asking so many question, i have a very little knowledge.